# How to add hover button into card view

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to add edit and delete button into card view after hover it.
Here is my code

```
<div class="card">  //image section
    <img class="card-img-top" alt="Card image" style="width:50%" src="images/img1">
    <div class="card-body">
    <div class="button" onClick="updateData()">
        <i class="fa fa-edit" style="font-size:24px"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="button" onClick="deleteData()">
        <span aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:40px">&times;</span>
    </div>'
    <p class="card-text">Text description</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to display the two button when I hover on card. How can I do that?

Comment: you can take the answer below!!

Comment: Thanks all for answering, but whenever I am adding the `link` or `script` line in my html code, my main web design become changed. Then what should I do?

Comment: Thanks for answers. But by adding the `link` or `script` line in code, my main web design become changed. `<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"integrity="sha384HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;900display=swap"rel="stylesheet"> `

Comment: you would have to add it for jquery its compulsory if you are changing the DOM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below selector

```
   button {
   display: none; /* Hide button */
   }

   .divbutton:hover button {
   display: block; /* On :hover of div show button */
   }
```

**Demo**

```css
.card {
    height: 30px;
    background: #000;
}

button {
    display: none;
}

.card:hover button {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/3aa0d20210.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card"> 
    <img class="card-img-top" alt="Card image" style="width:50%" src="images/img1">
    <div class="card-body">
    <button class="button" onClick="updateData()">
        <i class="fa fa-edit" style="font-size:24px"></i>
    </button>
    <button class="button" onClick="deleteData()">
        <span aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:40px">&times;               </span>
    </button>'
    <p class="card-text">Text description</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also make sure you assign some `height` or `min-height` to your `div` element, else it will be `0` as it doesn't hold any content. Also, don't use `display: none;` as inline style, as inline styles have highest specificity, and hence, you will be forced to use `!important` which is bad.

In the above example am using `button {/*Styles*/}` but that is a general element selector, so make sure you define a `class` to your `button` element.

Comment: why is it giving a flickering effect??? dont know how it is accepted.

Comment: @nikhilsugandh Because what I think he needs pure CSS, because there is no `jquery` tag in the question

Comment: @Aditya please do check "SUFFICE" in my answer if the post not tagged jquery

Answer (score 1):

This would suffice:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="Description" content="Enter your description here" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <title>

    </title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.1/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
        <div id="outer" style="display:none">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(
            $(".card").mouseenter(function() {
                $("#outer").css("display", "block");
            }),
            $(".card").mouseleave(function() {
                $("#outer").css("display", "none");
            })
        )
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

check:
https://jsfiddle.net/L46ug3bt/

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's some Javascript code that can do this:

```js
$(() => {
  $(".card").on("mouseenter", () => { // When the mouse enters the card
    $(".btn").removeClass("d-none") // Remove the d-none class
  });
  $(".card").on("mouseleave", () => { // The opposite
    $(".btn").addClass("d-none")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/3aa0d20210.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="card">
  <!-- image section -->
  <img class="card-img-top" alt="Card image" style="width:50%" src="images/img1">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="btn btn-success d-none" onClick="updateData()">
      <i class="fa fa-edit" style="font-size:24px"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="btn btn-danger d-none" onClick="deleteData()">
      <span aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:40px">&times;</span>
    </div>'
    <p class="card-text">Text description</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The "d-none" class adds `display: none` to the buttons. BTW, I'm pretty sure that `.button` doesn't exist in BS4. Maybe you're doing BS3?

Comment: The question was not tagged with JQuery. Also, while you may have provided a working solution, good answers should answer the original question, which you didn't do here.

Comment: Bootstrap includes jQuery, but yeah. Could be better.